# Cloud Functions logger SDK for iOS (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-functions

I have an iOS app written in Swift. I want to log events from my app to Google's Cloud Functions logger SDK. How do I manage it in Swift?

There is a documentation from Google: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/writing-and-viewing-logs?hl=en&gen=2nd#logger-sdk but it does not mention neither Swift, nor Objective-C.

Nonetheless, there is `FIRLogger.h` class in `FirebaseCore` in Firebase's cocoapod.
This class provides even `FIRLoggerWrapper` with a neat method:

```
+ (void)logWithLevel:(FIRLoggerLevel)level
         withService:(FIRLoggerService)service
            withCode:(NSString *)messageCode
         withMessage:(NSString *)message
            withArgs:(va_list)args;
```

but the logger seems not to be public and I gave up trying to import it directly or through Bridging-Header.

Clear instructions on importing and a working code sample in Swift will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Cloud logger is for cloud functions; serverless compute running in Google's cloud. There are other logging solutions available, such as sentry.io

Comment: `Crashlytics` is the logging alternative, `Logger`/`os_log` appears in it too

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be no official solution but personally I use [GoogleCloudLogging](https://github.com/DnV1eX/GoogleCloudLogging). The package seems to be abandoned, but I've forked it to make a few changes and everything is still working great.